# How to do a row-wise sum in an array formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sum

Say I have the following basic spreadsheet:

```
    A   B   C   D
1  -2   4   2  12
2  -1   1   0
3   0   0   0  22
4   1   1   2  12
5   2   4   6
6   3   9  12
```

The A column has integers from -2 to 3.

The B column has the a column value squared.

The C column is the row sum of A and B so C1 is =SUM(A1:B1).

D1 has =MAX(C1:C6) and this max is the result I need to get with a single formula.

D3 is =MAX(SUM(A1:B6))  entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, but it just results in a regular sum.
D4 is =MAX(A1:A6+B1:B6)  with ctrl+shift+enter, and this works and gives the correct result of 12.

However the problem with D4 is that I need to be able to handle large dynamic ranges without entering endless sums. Say SUM(A1:Z1000) would be A1:A1000+B1:B1000+....+Z1:Z1000 which is not a reasonable formula.

So how can I do something like =MAX(SUM(A1:Z1000)) such that it would sum the rows A1:Z1 to A1000:Z1000 and give me the final row-wize max.

I can only use base Excel, so no helper columns and no VBA function.

**UPDATE**
Since there have not been any successful answers, I have to assume it is not possible with current Excel versions.

So I am trying to build this function in VBA and this is what I have so far.

```
Function MAXROWSUM(Ref As Range) As Double
    Dim Result, tempSum As Double
    Dim Started As Boolean
    Started = False
    Result = 0
    For Each Row In Ref.Rows
        tempSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Row)
        If (Started = False) Then
            Result = tempSum
            Started = True
        ElseIf tempSum > Result Then
            Result = tempSum
        End If
    Next Row
    MAXROWSUM = Result
End Function
```

This function works and is quite fast with less than 100k rows, but if the row count in the range approaches the possible 1 million, the function becomes very slow taking several seconds, even if most of the range is empty.
Is there a way to significantly optimize the current code, by possibly filtering out any empty rows?
In my example if I enter MAXROWSUM(A1:B1000000) it will work, but will be slow, can I make this very fast?

Comment: yes A1 + B1 = 2, i had ypos at first wiht C1 being -2 which I fixed.sorry.

Comment: @Big Ben. Morning blindness. I'll delete.

Comment: Thanks for the rescue @MichaelE. If D3 = Max(Sum(A1+B6)) then D3 = Max(C1:C6) because column C has A+B. The maximum isn't 22.

Comment: @Variatus - `MAX(SUM(A1:B6))` isn't the same as `MAX(A1:A6+B1:B6)` (as an array formula).

Comment: @BigBen I'm wondering if there's a way to use `Index` or `Offset` to split the rows/columns for that

Comment: @BigBen Figured it out - just needed to go back to basics:  this was a Maths problem, not a Programming one xD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution is [Matrix Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), via [the `MMULT` function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/mmult-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb)

How this works is as follows:  currently, you have an `X*N` array/matrix, which you want to change into an `X*1` matrix (where each new row is the sum of the rows in the old matrix), and then take the maximum value.  To do this, you need to multiply it by an `N*1` matrix:  the two `N`s "cancel out".

The first step is simple:  **every value in your second matrix is `1`**

Example: [6*2] ∙ [2*1] = [6*1]

```
[[-2][ 4]             [[ 2]
 [-1][ 1]    [[ 1]     [ 0]
 [ 0][ 0]  ∙  [ 1]] =  [ 0]
 [ 1][ 1]              [ 2]
 [ 2][ 4]              [ 6]
 [ 3][ 9]]             [12]]
```

We then `MAX` this:

```
=MAX(MMULT(A1:B6,{1;1}))
```

To generate our second array dynamically (i.e. for any size), we can use the first Row of our table, convert it entirely to `1` (for example, "Column number > 0"), and then `TRANSPOSE` this to be a column instead of a row.  This can be written as `TRANSPOSE(--(COLUMN(A1:B1)>0))`

Put it all together, and we get:

```
=MAX(MMULT(A1:B6, TRANSPOSE(--(COLUMN(A1:B1)>0))))
```

Since `MMULT` works with arrays - like `SUMPRODUCT` - we don't actually need to define this as an Array Formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> either!

If you wanted to do this column-wise instead, then you would need to **swap the arrays around** - Matrix Multiplication is *not commutative*:

```
=MAX(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(--(ROW(A1:A6)>0)), A1:B6))
```

[1*6] ∙ [6*2] = [2*1]

```
                              [[-2][ 4]
                               [-1][ 1]
[[ 1][ 1][ 1][ 1][ 1][ 1]]  ∙  [ 0][ 0]   =  [[ 3][19]]
                               [ 1][ 1]
                               [ 2][ 4]
                               [ 3][ 9]]
```

Comment: That works great, thank you. but I still need ctrl-shift-enter for the COLUMN(A1:B1). did your work without an array formula?

Comment: @MichaelE Yeah, it worked fine for me without needing to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.  I don't know if that's because I'm on Office-365; which version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1):

### SUMPRODUCT (The Unsung Hero)

The following are **not** array formulas.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(A:A+A:A^2))
```

If it doesn't work (older Excel), change to the exact range e.g.:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(A$1:A$1000+A$1:A$1000^2))
```

Comment: thanks, sumproduct is an alternative  to the array formula, but what I need is to handle a larger number of columns, such as A:Z without having to add them directly in a formula.

Comment: @MichaelE: If you could further explain. Where are the results for A1:Z1000 and should it do the same as I did but for rows?

Comment: A1:Z1000 can have any numbers, but expanding my column b to the right is fine but x^2 will quickly get too big. BUt if you want it can be A1:A1000+A1:A1000^2 + A1:A1000^3+...+A1:A1000^25 too many terms to enter individually.

Comment: @VBasic2008 This works when the values are related via a simple equation, like the example - but, what if each row is a day of the week, each column is a shop worker, and the values are "sales made"?  This method could not then work out "most sales per day".  (Also, this *is* an array formula, but `SUMPRODUCT` outputs the sum of the calculated array.  As a proper Array Formula, it's just `{=MAX(A:A+A:A^2)}`)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to do the function with basic Excel, so I had to use VBA.

I was able to create a reasonably fast VBA function that works.

```
Function MAXROWSUM(Ref As Range) As Double
    Dim Result, tempSum As Double
    Dim Started As Boolean
    Started = False
    LastDataRow = Ref.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Result = 0
    For Each Row In Ref.Rows
        tempSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Row)
        If Row.Row > LastDataRow Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If (Started = False) Then
            Result = tempSum
            Started = True
        ElseIf tempSum > Result Then
            Result = tempSum
        End If
    Next Row
    MAXROWSUM = Result
End Function
```

A key line is: `LastDataRow = Ref.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row` which finds the last populated row of the data range and stops the function past it. So entering a function with a million rows where only 100 or a 1000 rows have data will not cause excessive useless calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If your Excel version permits [array formulas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/preview-of-dynamic-arrays-in-excel/ba-p/252944), you can do it without VBA by using [`LET`](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-let/ba-p/1233572):

```
= LET(
    \formula, "Returns a vector of row/col sum of the given matrix.",
    input_your_matrix, select_your_matrix_here,
    input_sum_per_row, TRUE,    \comment, "Otherwise sum per columns.",
    \user, "Done!",
    
    m, input_your_matrix,
    b, input_sum_per_row,
    mT, IF( b, m, TRANSPOSE( m ) ),
    k, IF( b, COLUMNS( m ), ROWS( m ) ),
    s, SEQUENCE( k, 1, 1, 0 ),
    sum, MMULT( mT, s ),
    o, IF( b, sum, TRANSPOSE( sum ) ),
    output, o,
    output )
```

The above formula has 2 inputs, found between the `\formula` and `\user` lines (each of which are defined in the subsequent formula argument):

1. `input_your_matrix` is the data you want to calculate a sum over
2. `input_sum_per_row` is set to `TRUE` to sum over rows, `FALSE` to sum over columns

---

To answer your example, I would use the above-proposed `LET` formula as such:

- in cell `C1`, and by replacing `select_your_matrix_here` with `A1:B6` (it will spill over `C1:C6`)
- if you only care about the result in `D1`, you can simply wrap the `LET` with a `MAX`

**EDIT**:

- if you only care about the results in column `D`, which I now understand to be a running-max, you will have to create the column `C` using the `LET`, and then applying the single-celled formula `= MAX(C$1:C1)` in `D1` and drag it down to `D6`