# How to remove blank rows in FILTER in Microsoft 365 Excel

Tags: excel, filter

In Microsoft 365 Excel, the new FILTER function didn't work to remove blank rows by using the expected <>"" comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work.

```
=FILTER(A5:L1000,A5:A1000>" ","")
```

By using `> " "`, the comparison worked to eliminate blank rows, as nearly every character will have a greater value (when sorted) than a single space. Sorting order uses comparisons from the ascii table (see http://www.asciitable.com).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem of <>"", except that there is a real blank of " " in your cells.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

English Excel Language:

```
=FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK((A:A))))
```

German Excel Language:

```
=FILTER(A:A;NICHT(ISTLEER((A:A))))
```

Best regards Chris

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out table rows of data that are fully blank while retaining all rows with data in at least one column and retaining table integrity (some blanks will still be present) then this can be accomplished with a matrix multiplication formula:

```
=LET(data, Sheet1!B1:E100, table, Sheet1!A1:E100, FILTER(table&"",MMULT(LEN(data),TRANSPOSE(--(COLUMN(data)>0)))>0))
```

Here you create the filter criteria from matrix multiplication of the length of all strings in the data field against a unit matrix which gives you the sum of all characters present in a row using `MMULT(LEN(data),TRANSPOSE(--(COLUMN(data)>0)))`.

[reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61476755/3688861]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61476755/3688861)

This array can then be tested to see if it is greater than 0 for the filter criteria.