# count columnwise if corresponding parts of columns are not empty

Tags: excel-formula

How can I count the number of non-empty cells in the top 3 rows, if the 6 cells below are not empty.

So for the sample below only the x in column `A`, `D` and `E` from the top 3 rows schould be countes, as they have non-empty cells below them in the bottom part.

Currently I'm just adding the results from every single column

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A4:A10,"<>"&"")>0,COUNTIF(A1:A3,"<>"&""))+IF(COUNTIF(B4:B10,"<>"&"")>0,COUNTIF(B1:B3,"<>"&""))+...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61476755/10068520) answer. Be sure to honor the answer of @Chronocidal if you find this post here helpful.

[image]

For the sum of the upper part, the **ARRAY Formula -> CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER** is:

```
=SUM(
     (MMULT(TRANSPOSE(--(ROW(A1:A3)>0)); (--(A1:E3<>""))))
    *(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(--(ROW(A4:A9)>0)); (--(A4:E9<>"")))>0)
)
```

The `ROW`-functions need to span as many rows as the corresponding count-arrays do have rows. The `3x1`-rowarray then gets `TRANSPOSE`d to an `1x3`-array. With the `3x5`-array we get a `1x5`-countarray. So `[3x1]*[3x5]` is transposed to and gives `[1x3]*[3x5]=[1x5]`.

For the sum of the bottom part, the **ARRAY Formula -> CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER** is:

```
=SUM(
     (MMULT(TRANSPOSE(--(ROW(A1:A3)>0)); (--(A1:E3<>"")))>0)
    *(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(--(ROW(A4:A9)>0)); (--(A4:E9<>""))))
)
```