# Excel SUMPRODUCT and dynamic text conditions

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I am trying to do a summation of rows with certain dynamic conditions. I have rows like:

[image]

A can be only one value, K can have multiple OR-values. In the end M is to be summed.

I have tried to use SUMPRODUCT() which works for column A but not for K. What I am looking for is something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(!$A$2:$A$20000="AA")*--(!$K$2:$K$20000="AA" OR "BB")*$M$2:$M$20000)
```

I know I can do ="AA" and then ="BB" but I need "AA" and "BB" to be dynamic based on other cells. And the number of arguments is different. I tried {"AA";"BB"} but I know this will not work as the match then needs to be in the same row.

Can it at all be achieved?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$20000="AA")*(($K$2:$K$20000="AA")+($K$2:$K$20000="BB"))*$M$2:$M$20000)
```

Note that:

- Since you are multiplying/adding arrays, there's no need to include the double unary's
- I don't know why you have a `!` in your example formula.
- To return an `OR` array of `TRUE;FALSE`, we add.

Your comments still do not provide a clear explanation of what you are making dynamic.

But to create a dynamic `OR` for column `K`, including testing for column `A` and summing column `M`, you can do the following:

For column K, let us assume that your possible `OR`'s are entered separately in the range F2:F10

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(--($K$2:$K$20000=TRANSPOSE($F$2:$F$10)),--(ROW($F$2:$F$10)>0))*($A$2:$A$20000="AAA")*$M$2:$M$20000)
```

The matrix multiplication will produce a single column of `19,999` entries which will be a 1 for matches of any of the `OR`'s and `0` if it does not match.

See [How to do a row-wise sum in an array formula in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334490/how-to-do-a-row-wise-sum-in-an-array-formula-in-excel)
 for information about the `MMULT` function in this application.

In the above formula, "blanks" in the `OR` range (`F2:F10`) will also match blank entries in column K.  So it is conceivable that if there is a blank in K and F and a AAA in col A and a value in column M that a wrong result might be returned.

To avoid that possibility, we can use a dynamic formula to size column F where we are entering our `OR` values:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$10,1):INDEX($F$2:$F$10,COUNTA($F$2:$F$10))
```

will return only the values in col F that are not blank (assuming no blanks within the column)

So:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(--($K$2:$K$20000=TRANSPOSE(INDEX($F$2:$F$10,1):INDEX($F$2:$F$10,COUNTA($F$2:$F$10)))),--(ROW(INDEX($F$2:$F$10,1):INDEX($F$2:$F$10,COUNTA($F$2:$F$10)))>0))*($A$2:$A$20000="AAA")*$M$2:$M$20000)
```

Given this data:

[image]

the last formula will return a value of `5` (sum of `M2,M3,M7`)

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that "AA" and "BB"  is dynamic from a range or array, so there might be "CC" and "DD" as well... The ! should not have been there, it was a part of a sheet reference.

Comment: @KasperSommer just replace those constants with a cell reference when you are storing the variables.

Comment: Thanks, @ron-rosenfeld, but how will you make this part dynamical: (($K$2:$K$20000="AA")+($K$2:$K$20000="BB").........+($N$2:$N$20000="nn"))?

Comment: @KasperSommer Please be more specific about your possible parameters and arguments.  Other than your use of the word "dynamic" which I'm not sure what it means in this context, the only definitive explanation I've seen was `"A can be only one value, K can have multiple OR-values. In the end M is to be summed."`

Comment: I am sorry if I have been unclear. The point is, that I do not know how many OR values K can have. That is why putting each condition as ="AA" and the next ="BB" does not work - because in some cases there will also be ="CC" and maybe ="DD". This is based on a range or array. That is also why I stated `I know I can do ="AA" and then ="BB"` in the original post. Just hardcoding these two conditions will not do it.

Comment: @KasperSommer At some point, you need to decide and/or code the `OR` values for column `K` and I'm still not sure how you are planning to input the information. Without that, it is difficult to create a solution. But I will edit to show an example.

Comment: I think that was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMIFS with SUMPRODUCT wrapper:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($M$2:$M$20000,$A$2:$A$20000,"AA",$K$2:$K$20000,{"AA","BB"}))
```

Comment: I think this is very close to what I need. However, I get problems adding multiple condition arrays like: =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($M$2:$M$20000,$A$2:$A$20000,"AA",$K$2:$K$20000,{"AA","BB"}, $N$2:$N$20000,{"DD","EE"}, $O$2:$O$20000,{"MM","NN"})) - it should be AND to every condition and OR in each array.

Comment: You will need to do something like Ron's then. The sumif only allows two arrays on horizontal and one vertical.