# Is it possible to return specific number of rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula like below with a nested `SEQUENCE()` function that that points to another cell that calculates the total number of rows with data for a given column. This returns just the number of data points I need in the SPILL range.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table3,SEQUENCE(J2,ROWS(J2)),{54,28,30,39,48,51}),"")
```

I am trying to accomplish something similar but with the below IF() function - I wanted to know, can I nest a SEQUENCE to achieve the same result here? Or, is it possible to tell the function only to return the number of rows that contain data? In column C or F2 for example I don't have to screen all 2000 rows, maybe the data is only length 120 rows. The way I have it written though it screens all 2000 - and I feel this could be hindering performance.

```
=IFERROR(IF($C$2:$C$2000>0,F2:$F$2000+250,IF(TODAY()-90>D2:$D$2000,"Sell Now","Check back in 30")),"")
```

This second formula does not point to a table array. Just a range.

Comment: You could use LET to calculate the last non-empty row (something like `=LET(lastrow,LOOKUP(2,1/(C2:C2000<>""),ROW(C2:C2000)),C2:INDEX(C:C,lastrow))` and do the same for column F `F2:INDEX(F:F,lastrow)`

Comment: You can find some criteria to filter your data on then use `MMULT` with `TRANSPOSE(--(COLUMN(data)>0))` to map the 2D matches onto a 1D filter list. An example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70208737/3688861